# FIFO pipe is always readable in select()

Tags: c, select, file-descriptor, fifo

In C pseudo-code:

```
while (1) {
    fifo = open("fifo", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    fd_set read;
    FD_SET(fifo, &read);
    select(nfds, &read, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

The process sleeps as triggered by `select()` until another process writes into `fifo`. Afterwards it will always find `fifo` as a readable file descriptor.

How to avoid this behavior (that is, after `fifo` has been read once, how to make it be found as unreadable until it gets another write?)

Comment: So, what do you want to occur?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You opened that FIFO as read only (O_RDONLY), whenever there is no writer to the FIFO, the read end will receive an `EOF`.

Select system call will return on `EOF` and for every `EOF` you handle there will be a new `EOF`. This is the reason for the observed behavior.

To avoid this open that FIFO for both reading and writing (O_RDWR). This ensures that you have at least one writer on the FIFO thus there wont be an `EOF` and as a result select won't return unless someone writes to that FIFO.

Comment: That was the correct answer to prevent running an endless loop of EOL detection

Comment: this was the correct answer for me.  Though, in my case I had minor variant of it: pipe always returns 2 fds - 1 for read and 1 for write; in my case i explicitly closed the write end (following code example from a C/S application).  Hence, I encountered same problem that the read end was always ready for read because of the EOF.  THANKS FOR THE TIP

Comment: OMG, was looking for something like that for literally 4 hours. Finally found the solution here. +1

Comment: when i do this I never register a response in the select block from the write end of the fifo. it just stalls. Even if i redirect string from terminal to the fifo, i still get nothing

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to read until `read()` returns `EWOULDBLOCK` (or `EAGAIN`), or craps out with an error.

What you are saying simply cannot be happening unless the operating system (or runtime) that you are using is buggy. Otherwise you must be doing something wrong. For example, `select()` is using level-triggered I/O. I'd think that, most likely, you are not draining the socket completely, and so `select()` always indicates that you have something left in there (this does not happen with edge-triggered event notifications).

Below is a simple example that shows how one should read until the `read()` returns `EWOULDBLOCK` in order to avoid leaving descriptor in readable state (I've compiled and tested this on OS X, and there is also mostly no error checking, but you should get the idea):

```
/*
 * FIFO example using select.
 *
 * $ mkfifo /tmp/fifo
 * $ clang -Wall -o test ./test.c
 * $ ./test &
 * $ echo 'hello' > /tmp/fifo
 * $ echo 'hello world' > /tmp/fifo
 * $ killall test
 */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    int n;
    fd_set set;
    ssize_t bytes;
    size_t total_bytes;
    char buf[1024];

    fd = open("/tmp/fifo", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(fd, &set);

    for (;;) {
        n = select(fd+1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (!n)
            continue;
        if (n == -1) {
            perror("select");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &set)) {
            printf("Descriptor %d is ready.\n", fd);
            total_bytes = 0;
            for (;;) {
                bytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
                if (bytes > 0) {
                    total_bytes += (size_t)bytes;
                } else {
                    if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                        /* Done reading */
                        printf("done reading (%lu bytes)\n", total_bytes);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        perror("read");
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Basically, level-triggered I/O means that you get notified all the time if there is something to read, even though you might have been notified of this before. On a contrary, edge-triggered I/O means that you are getting notified only once every time new data arrives and it doesn't matter whether you read it or not. `select()` is a level-triggered I/O interface.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: I think the other answer contradicts this one, and is correct. `select` returns when a blocking `read` would return, and `read` returns `0` (signalling EOF) if no-one has your fifo open for writing. Your example program never does this because it has the fifo open for writing itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, presumably due to an operating system bug. I found that closing and reopening the fifo after each return from the select call solved the problem.