# Does socket select return on an EOF?

Tags: python, sockets, select

```
read, write, err = select.select([sock1, sock2], [], [])
```

If either sock1 or sock2 are closed from the other end and they begin receiving the EOF ("") then will select return them as readable or does it ignore that and continue blocking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The socket is marked readable on EOF so `select` will return the socket and `sock.read()` will return zero bytes.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594508/fifo-pipe-is-always-readable-in-select which discusses underlying C API.